# Django REST Framework: default fields in browseable API form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class XCall(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    send_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    backup_calls = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And a serializer for that model:

```
class CallSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='call-detail',
    )
    # some validation and custom field definitions
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = XCall
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'text', 'recipient', 'send_on', 'backup_calls', 'status')
        lookup_field= 'pk'
```

And here's the list view:

```
class CallList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CallSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrSuperuser,)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        auth_user = self.request.user
        obj.auth_user = auth_user

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the calls
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        auth = self.request.user
        if isinstance(auth, AnonymousUser):
            return []
        elif auth.is_superuser:
            return XCall.objects.all()
        else:
            return XCall.objects.filter(auth_user=auth)
```

In `CallList`'s browseable API, I see the following in the POST form at the bottom:
[image]

My question is: why is there no default value set for `send_on`, and there is one for `backup_calls`? I assumed that the form would follow the `XCall` model specification and use `datetime.now()` for defaulting the former, and leave `backup_calls` blank (since it's nullable). How can I get the form to follow the model specifications?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm currently running into it.

Answer (score 4):

You actually want to set an `initial` value, not a default value. See the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments). Your code should be:

```
from django.utils import timezone


class CallSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    send_on = serializers.DateTimeField(initial=timezone.now())
    ...
```

A default value is the value provided to an attribute if no value is set for the field. The distinction between `initial` and `default` arguments mirrors the difference between Django's `initial` argument for form fields and Django's `default` argument for model fields.

Answer (score 2):

There is a distinction between model defaults and initial values in forms.  This is especially the case for default values which are actually functions because they are only called when the instance is saved.  For example, which `now` do you want - this time at which the blank form is displayed, or the time at which the user presses "POST"?  Django applies the default when saving the model if the field value is missing.  To achieve what you want you need to manually set the default in the serialize field, for example:

```
class CallSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    send_on = serializers.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I am seeing the behavior you describe. When I try to post without send_on filled in, I get a validation error "This field is required". If you're saying Django applies the default on save, why the validation error? Some other bits of info: 1) I'm on Django 1.6; I vaguely remember all of this working differently before I upgraded from 1.4. 2) Strangely, I see the default form values working as I expect in Django development mode, but not in my production env (Django + Apache + mod_wsgi).

Comment: And also, this answer doesn't explain why I see a default value for the `backup_calls` field. I'm not explicitly setting it in `CallSerializer`

Comment: IIRC, field validation first happens in the form.  The form sees that nothing was entered into send_on, it is required and according to the form field there is no default, so it raises an exception before getting to the model.  I don't know why it would work differently in production though - sounds like it could be some weird caching issue.

Comment: I suspect that because `backup_calls` is an integer field, it is using a textbox formatted for integers which shows a zero default. You might be able to see this by inspecting the html.  The fact that the field is set with blank and null makes it look like a bug though.

Comment: Ok, I see that my dev env was running DRF 2.3.6, and production was on 2.3.10. So that accounts for the different behaviors. So did 2.3.6 have a side-effect that made it respect the model defaults?

Comment: I tried the setting the `DateTimeField` default value, it is not showing up in the form nor is the form allowing to be submitted if left blank.

Comment: Make sure to add it to the list of fields.  Maybe try it with a different name first to make sure its not clashing with the model field.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the defaulted value isn't showing up. The field is there but no value. Do you mean something like `send_on2 = serializers.DateTimeField(source='send_on', default=datetime.now)`? That still didn't work